# Do we need differential routing TX and RX in Ethernet RMII MAC to MAC Connection

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, microprocessor, phy, mac

I am implementing an Ethernet mac to mac connection between [SAMA5D27C-D1G-CU](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atsama5d27c-d1g#) and [FS32K148UJT0VLQT](https://www.nxp.com/part/FS32K148UJT0VLQT#/) micro-controller.

In MAC to MAC communication PHY TX is connected to RX of MAC and vice versa as shown below.

[image]

In Ethernet,the RX and TX are differential signals with characteristic impedance of 100 Ohm.

My Question is ,**Do we need to follow differential routing for RX and TX in this MAC to MAC communication?**

Comment: schematic too small, can't read a single word.

Comment: I removed that schematic.Not able to upload high resolution image.Actually it is not required.I am following the connection as shown in the MAC-MAC interface image.

Comment: you can't upload images over 2 MB, but a 4-colored schematic would be a few kBs only and such things have been posted several thousand times here. If you want people to refer to your specific connections, I'd recommend trying again to post a higher-resolution version of your schematic.

Comment: Schematic is added

Comment: Protip: save a reduced-color PNG copy locally, then upload the file. It will host the file verbatim, and you see the file size before uploading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the Ethernet copper MDI signals are differential, the MII/RMII are not.

The signals are not differential so they do not require differential routing.

It would even be wrong to route them as differential pairs as they are not differential signals but unrelated signals.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Datasheet of the NXP controller](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K1xx.pdf) (Page 74, Table 49)

[image]

and the timing diagramm per [Datasheet of the NXP controller](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K1xx.pdf) (Page 75, Figure 25/26)

[image]

i would suspect you don't really need to take special care of the tracks.

However, [the layout recommendations for the SAMA5D2](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/SAMA5D2-Layout-Recommendations-Application%20Note-DS00002814A.pdf) (Page 8) recommend:

- It is recommended to route all signals of the same data lane (TX or RX) on the same layer.
- The length difference between the TX data and TXCK lanes should not exceed 300 mils.
- The length difference between the RX data and RXCK lanes should not exceed 300 mils.
- The impedance of any single-end signal trace should be 50 ± 10% Ohm.

I would route them **single-ended** with *some degree* of length/group matching, and **as controlled impedance** on a inner layer. I would *avoid* excessive use of vias and long distances (>10cm).

This [Blogpost](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2019-mii-and-rmii-routing-guidelines-for-ethernet) underlines the conclusion.

Comment: You are referring to MII which is 25 MHz. OP is using RMII which is 50 MHz. Clean 50 MHz clock requires many harmonics of 50 MHz to pass properly. First harmonic is 3x at 150 MHz and second is 5x at 250 MHz. The more passes properly, the better. I would say it does need a bit of special attention, instead of no special attention.

Comment: @Justme I agree - as stated: "... i would suspect you don't really need to take special care of the tracks. However...."